# XCTest: App is terminated after changing device language

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

My UI test scenario is simple. Change device language in settings app and open my test app to check if the language in app is changed accordingly. And I would check about 5 languages so that involve switching between test app and settings app.

The problem is that when I applied the language change in device settings, the test is stopped. It shows "Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9" in console, I think that means my app was terminated by some cause.

So is that a correct behavior? If it is, how could I check test app's language after changing the device language?

Here is an example about the test case:

```
    func testExample() throws {
        // 1. lauch settingsApp
        let settingsApp = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.Preferences")
        settingsApp.launch()
        
        // 2. change device language in settingsAPP and apply the change
        // MARK: App was terminated: Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9
        
        // 3. launch my app to check if language was changed accordingly
        let app = XCUIApplication()
        app.launch()
    }
```

And system failures in XCTestResult.
[image]

Comment: "So is that a correct behavior?" Yes. Certain settings changes do crash the app deliberately and this is one of them.

Comment: @matt Thanks for the quick answer:) So may I know how could I test my scenario, or it is not possible.

Comment: I don't know what scenario you mean. What is the "system under test" here? It cannot be Apple's Settings app; you know what it does and it is not yours to test.  Nor is the way localization works yours to test. What you can test is that if the language is x then this button title is y. But that is not even a UI test; it is trivially a unit test (or acceptance test). There is no point testing that the phone works like a phone.

Comment: Also this is exactly why Apple gave you _test plans_, which automatically test repeatedly in different languages. Use the tools you're given as they're meant to be used and things will go a lot better.

Comment: My scenario is basically change device language in settings then check if the language is changed accordingly in test app. Since my app is localized with several languages, these steps would go many times. Well, there is no SUT because it is an UI Test case. And yeah I get your point, maybe I shouldn't test this way, instead to use different test plan to define the device language or what ever else, I will check on my side.

Comment: Yes, after a bit searching, it turns out I should add different configurations in a test plan, and within each configuration, to fill one language. Then run all configurations.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said. It's a common enough problem that you should answer your own question when you've worked out the details.

Comment: Thanks, I would do that, before that I need to figure out how to run non-localization test cases with one configuration(English) and localization test cases with all configurations(languages), if they are in the same test plan, because by default they would run with all configurations. Or I need to split them into two test plans, any advices?

Comment: Multiple test plans is definitely part of how you're intended to work with this.